# Unable to read from css-loader

Tags: css

i have a problem doing npm start, it seems to be a bug with css-loader but i cant fix it.

```
.Toastify__slide-exit--bottom-center {
  animation-name: Toastify__slideOutDown; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=ReactToastify.css.map */
^
      Invalid CSS after "": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@inrupt/solid-style-guide/css/main.css
Unknown word (2:1)

  1 |
> 2 | var content = require("!!../../../css-loader/index.js??ref--8-oneOf-3-1!../../../postcss-loader/src/index.js??postcss!./main.css");
    | ^
  3 |
  4 | if(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];
  5 |
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
```

I read this but i cant make this work: https://github.com/ReactJSResources/react-webpack-babel/issues/197

I also modified the webpack.config.js adding : `const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');`

And:

```
{
          test: /\.s?css$/,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                localsConvention: 'camelCase',
                modules: true
              }
            },
            'sass-loader',
            'import-glob-loader'
          ]
        },
        { 
          test: /\.css$/, loader: 'css-loader'
        },
```

If someone can help please...

Thanks very much.

Comment: What is in that `main.css` file? The error suggests there's JS in there, which seems odd.

Comment: You have JS code inside `.css` file. That is invalid

Comment: I didnt touch the main.css file, i dont know what it is but i think the problem is in this other line:

`/*# sourceMappingURL=ReactToastify.css.map */
^
      **Invalid CSS after "": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"**`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using React ??
and trying to load css as module using:

```
import styles from "./style.css";
```

if yes:
In react 16.13 and all later versions, for css module you have to use different file naming like as:

css file name: 
ComponentName.module.css (assuming your component name is ComponentName)
also the css file resides in the same folder as Component

therefore the import statement will look like:

```
import styles from "./ComponentName.module.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes im using react but i think my problem is here:

```
`.Toastify__slide-exit--bottom-center {
  animation-name: Toastify__slideOutDown; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=ReactToastify.css.map */
^
      **Invalid CSS after "": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"**
Failed to compile.
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@inrupt/solid-style-guide/css/main.css
Unknown word (2:1)

  1 |
> 2 | var content = require("!!../../../css-loader/index.js??ref--8-oneOf-3-1!../../../postcss-loader/src/index.js??postcss!./main.css");
    | ^
  3 |
  4 | if(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];
  5 |
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)`
```

Comment: In this concrete line : Invalid CSS after "": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"